# how to pass data from view to controller in angularjs by defining a multi-dimension array using ng-init in view

Tags: angularjs

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp"ng-model="user"ng-init="user=[{'name':'A','email':'a@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'banglore'},
{'name':'B','email':'B@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'pune'},
{'name':'C','email':'C@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'hyderebad'}] "ng-init="fuser='hello'">
<div  ng-controller="myctrl" >
<table align="left">
<tr>

<td><ul>
    <h1>City</h1>

    <li ng-repeat="x in user">{{x.city}}</li>
</ul></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table align="center">
<tr>
<th>Select User</th>
<td>

<select ng-model="u" ng-change="getuser(name,email,mobile,city)">
    <option value="">Choose name</option>
    <option  ng-repeat="x in user" value="{{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>

</select></td>

</tr>


<tr>

    <table align="center" cellpadding="5" ng-model="table" bgcolor='skyblue'>
    <caption><h2>User info</h2></caption>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
        <th>city</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="row in user|filter:fuser">
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        <td>{{row.mobile}}</td>
        <td>{{row.city}}</td>
        </tr>


</table>
<tr>
</table>

</div>

</div>
<script>
var obj = angular.module("myapp",[]);
        obj.controller("myctrl",function($scope)
            {

                    $scope.u=this.response;}




                $scope.getuser=function(uname)
                {


                    $scope.fuser=uname;

                }


            });
```

please help me to extract the data from array into table by filtering the data using dropdown option and diplay the relevant data.i can not use $http event and i dont want to initializa my array in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered your requirement that you dont want to put your data in controller,but i dont know how to do that so i followed the regular procedure....Hope this will helps you

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user=[{'name':'A','email':'a@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'banglore'},
{'name':'B','email':'B@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'pune'},
{'name':'C','email':'C@gmail.com','mobile':'9494563132','city':'hyderebad'}];

 $scope.getuser=function(uname){
for(var i=0;i<$scope.user.length;i++){
  if($scope.user[i].name==uname){
    $scope.e=$scope.user[i];
  
}
}
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table align="left">
<tr>

<td><ul>
    <h1>City</h1>

    <li ng-repeat="x in user">{{x.city}}</li>
</ul></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table align="center">
<tr>
<th>Select User</th>
<td>

<select ng-model="x" ng-change="getuser(x)">
    <option value="">Choose name</option>
    <option  ng-repeat="x in user" value="{{x.name}}">{{x.name}}</option>

</select></td>

</tr>


<tr>

    <table align="center" cellpadding="5" ng-model="table" bgcolor='skyblue'>
    <caption><h2>User info</h2></caption>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>mobile</th>
        <th>city</th>
        </tr>

        <tr >
        <td>{{e.name}}</td>
        <td>{{e.email}}</td>
        <td>{{e.mobile}}</td>
        <td>{{e.city}}</td>
        </tr>


</table>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the response SaE,is there any chance to extract data from view i.e., by defining array in  ng-init directive  of the view @SaE

Comment: i am wondering why you want to extract it from view??From where you will get that data??